# Keyframe animation is lagging when there is a lot of content on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, keyframe

I want to add animated circle, when I'm clicking to some div.
So I'm handling clicks to the element and adding zero-sized div to the click coordinates. Also, I added keyframe animation for this div to increase its width and height. Finally, here is animation-div styles:

```
div.clickEffect {
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Adding this div in react:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.className = 'clickEffect';
d.style.top = `${y}px`;
d.style.left = `${x}px`;

const animation = keyframes`
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: ${minSize}px;
        height: ${minSize}px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0px #ff00ff;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        width: ${minSize + radius}px;
        height: ${minSize + radius}px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0px #ff00ff;
    }
`;
d.style.animation = `${animation} 1s ease-out`;
```

This amimation is smooth when there is not much content on the page. But it's lagging when there is a lot of content on the page. Is there any way to make this anmation always smooth?

Comment: Use _transforms_ `scale()` instead of `width/height`. Animations using `transform` make use of GPU which other properties doesn't.

Comment: I left just `scale` and `translate` but it's still lagging
`
0% {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            100% {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(200);
            }
`